# I am getting an error "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". How do i resolve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, syntax, aws-iot

I have an error message "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"
Kindly help resolve

[Image contains the code for which im getting an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C7iU.png)

Comment: Hey Mahima, please include images here in your question. Even better, please include the actual error here, as well as the code that caused the error! Having said that, you are missing a closing parenthesis on the line `device.publish(...`

Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it'll help make sure your questions do not get closed, as well as get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `device.publish[...]` line is missing the closing parenthesis at the end. Next time please post your code inline

Answer (score 0):

you just missed out one **)** bracket on end of the following code:

```
device.publish('MyBusPolicy',JSON.stringify({test_data:'nodejs....'}))
```